# Generating Custom Loggers

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I want to generate a custom Logger in log4j2. I tried the following described [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html):

```
java -cp log4j-core-2.6.jar org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools.Generate$CustomLogger Logger TEST=550 PRODUKTION=200 > Logger.java
```

I got the log4j-core-2.6.jar file from [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/download.html). If I try to run the command in my terminal(I use osx10.11.5) I get the following error:

```
Error: Main method not found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools.Generate, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Kindly Regards!

EDIT: Thanks to Alexandre Cartapanis I had to change the command as follows:

```
java -cp log4j-core-2.6.jar 'org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools.Generate$CustomLogger' MyLogger TEST=550 PRODUKTION=200 > Logger.java
```

Comment: According to your link, you should replace ``> Logger.jar`` by a ``> Logger.java``, compile the java file and then adds it to your application classpath

Comment: Huh sorry was just a bad copy paste. It's still the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to surround the command with ''.

Here the error says that java cannot found a main method in the "org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools.Generate" class, but the main method is in "org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools.Generate$CustomLogger".

Probably a trouble with the "$" in the class name. I'm not an expert into macos shell, but i think the solution is to escape the "$" character.